# How do I remove the characters in a string that are included in another string

Tags: javascript

How do I remove the characters in a string that are included in another string?

```
let mustRemoved = "rin8cu73s9b";
let string = "CatsAndDogsAreAwesome"
```

Output Must Be : `atAdDogAeAweome`

What I have tried:

```js
let regEx = new RegExp(mustRemoved, "ig");
let replaceMask = "";
let final = string.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your current code? What is the problem?

Comment: You need a [character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#types): `let mustRemoved = "[rin8cu73s9b]";`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the string into an array of characters, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the characters which are included in `mustRemoved`, then join the resulting array.

```js
let mustRemoved = "rin8cu73s9b".toLowerCase();
let string = "CatsAndDogsAreAwesome"

let res = [...string].filter(e => !mustRemoved.includes(e.toLowerCase())).join('')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: the problem is i cant removed 'C' the code must be incasesensitive if there is c so C must be removed too @Spectric

Comment: @MuammarHM I've updated my answer so it's no longer case sensitive. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regex so that it matches with every character in `mustRemoved` string, like this:

```js
let mustRemoved = "rin8cu73s9b";
let string = "CatsAndDogsAreAwesome"
let regEx = new RegExp(mustRemoved.split('').join('|'), "ig");
let replaceMask = "";
let final = string.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
console.log(final)
```